# How to get the data in flask from the HTML input with changing the url of website

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, flask

I have a input box in HTML and what I want is to get the data that get input in that box when button is clicked. I know how to get data from the form

```
ex =  request.form['example'];
```

I want to get the data in flask just like above but for the input box which look like this -

```
<div class="form-inline" id="inputDiv">
      <center>
        <input class="form-group" id="msg-content" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Send a message" />
        <button class="btn btn-lg" onclick="sendMsg()" id="sendBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
      </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a form to return data you normally want to put it inside a `<form>` element.

This tells the browser that it should return the inner elements when the form is submitted by a button with the attribute `type="submit"`. You should give the input attribute `name="example"` in order to retrieve it in flask. I'm not sure what javascript you are calling with the sendMsg() function, but I am guessing that a `<form>` element is your best solution. Something like this:

```
<form action="/url/to/send/form" method="POST">
  <center>
    <input class="form-group" name="example" id="msg-content" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Send a message" />
    <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="sendBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </center>
</form>
```

Then you should be able to retrieve in flask as you describe in your post.

Comment: Actually sendMsg() is a function in javascript which makes ajax call to send request  to the server with the inputted data. The thing is I need to make asynchronous call using ajax, that's why i wasn't using form element because you can't make asynchronous call with form, I might be wrong here but that's what i've read somewhere. But anyways I got answer, you could simply write var = request.get_data(), and this think worked for me.

Comment: Ahh I see, yes Ajax makes it a little more tricky but calling JavaScript is the way forward. I just had to do the same thing in a Django project, AJAX seems to be a great solution when things get a little more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Create your route

```
@app.route('/yayform',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def yayform():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)
```

Making sure to add form action to your HTML,

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/yayform" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your HTML in a form, something like:

```
<form id="inputDiv" method="post" action="/your_action">
  <!--- Your HTML input and button here --->
</form>
```

Note `method="POST"` and `action="/your_action"` .

`method="POST"` indicates you are initiating an HTTP Post request to a new page.

`action="/your_action"` is the URL you want to redirect to.  You'll have to replace that with your URL.

To touch on the previous answer, I don't recommend putting `"http://localhost:5000"` in the action as 1. it is unnecessary and 2. it may not be correct depending on how you're running your application, e.g, if you're running on a port that's not 5000.

In the python code behind:

```
@app.route('/your_action', methods = ['POST'])
def yourRoute():

   #Your code here
```

Comment: can we make asynchronous call and get the data from form element, I am not sure.